# Heredocument indented inside a function fails on execution

Tags: function, here-document

I have this a script containing a function and a function call. Inside the function there's an heredocument:

```
#!/bin/bash

DWA() {
    ......
    mysql -u root -p <<-MYSQL
        ......
    MYSQL
}
DWA
```

### The problem

The execution breaks with an error regarding heredocument delimiter (likely, due to the delimiter `MYSQL` being indented).

The problem didn't happen when I removed all leads (whitespaces/tabs).

### My question

Given functions strip all leading tabs (I don't know about other types of leads, like whitespaces), why do I encounter this problem and what, if at all, can be done against that?

Comment: Functions strip all leads?

Comment: I've read in the past that they are, or I was confused with something else.

Comment: Are you sure you're indenting with tabs and not with spaces?

Comment: @Arcticooling, I don't think I have ever heard anything like that however there is a lot I haven't heard about.  I think it's likely whatever you read does not apply in this case.  Here docs are sort of a special block of it's own, and as far as I know they require your ending delimiter to be at the beginning of the line with no leading whitespace.

Comment: I don't understand. I didn't ask why you're indenting. I just asked if you're sure that you're using tabs.

Comment: Sorry @igal, I think you were right. This does seem to be the case. the row with `MYSQL` was indented with spaces and not tabs...

Comment: @Arcticooling No worries. I think that's always the first thing to check with any tab-sensitive syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably not indenting your heredoc with tabs. Every line of the heredoc must be indented with a tab, including the first line (where the delimiter is introduced). Here is a test case for you:

```bsh
echo -e 'function heredoc() {\n\tcat <<-HEREDOC\n\t\tThis is a test\tHEREDOC\n} heredoc' > heredoc.sh
```

Try running that command and then running `heredoc.sh`. You should get the following output:

```
This is a test.
```

Alternatively, here is the same script but with the first line indented with spaces instead of a tab:

```
    echo -e 'function heredoc() {\n    cat <<-HEREDOC\n\t\tThis is a test\tHEREDOC\n} heredoc' > heredoc2.sh
```

If we run `heredoc2.sh` we get the following error output:

```
bash heredoc2.sh 
heredoc2.sh: line 4: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `HEREDOC')
heredoc2.sh: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```